# 503 errors on ISAPI module (rpcproxy.dll) when authentication / impersonation is enabled

Tags: windows, iis-7

I'm stuck on rpcproxy.dll install - when authentication is disabled the module works fine. However, when enabling basic authentication and providing username & password server responds with error 503. There are no entries on event log. I have tried moving the dll out of system32\rpcproxy and given wide execute permissions - with no success.

Where to start digging up what makes it fail with 503?

--- Solved:

Actually this was due my faulty testing methods (Microsoft specifically says in one of their document to not test directly towards the web server with http tools but use only rpcping) and I interpreted the message wrong. The problem proved to be in my RPC configuration and I was looking answers from wrong end.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a 32-bit DLL? If so, try sticking it in \Windows\SYSWOW64 and using \Windows\SYSWOW64\regsvr32.exe to register it (if it needs registering).